# Taylor serie for even function. Proof

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, taylor-expansion

We let $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ be infinitely often differentiable function and we let the Taylor series be:
$$\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\left(\left(\frac{f^{n}(0)}{n!}\right)x^n\right)
$$Let $\{a_n\}_{n\in \mathbb N }$ be $a_n=\frac{f^{n}(0)}{n!}$.
We have to assume that the Taylor series converges toward $f$ in an open interval $(-r,r)$ around zero. Then I have to show that if $a_{2n-1}=0$ for all $n\in \mathbb N$ so is $f(-x)=f(x)$ for all $x\in(-r,r)$.
How can I do it? I think I maybe can see on $kx^{2n}$ while all odd joints are zero while $a_{2n-1}=0$? But how can I prove it?

Comment: If $f(x)=\sum_n a_nx^n$ then what is $f(-x)$?

Comment: Then I get $$\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\left(\left(\frac{f^{n}(0)}{n!}\right)(-x)^n\right)$$. But can I reduce it to something smart I can use?

Comment: You like your factorials! I'd just write it as $\sum_n a_n(-x)^n$. When is that the same as $f(x)$?

Comment: Sorry. It's the same for x=0 or for all even exponents so for exponent 2n?

Comment: I can't see how I can use this to make a proof? Can you give me a hint?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Even and odd functions for Taylor serie](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3702026/even-and-odd-functions-for-taylor-serie)