# Even and odd functions for Taylor serie

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, even-and-odd-functions

I have asked this question before, sorry, but I'm still confused about how I can show it. Hope anybody can help me?

We let $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ be infinitely often differentiable function and we let the Taylor series be:
$$\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\left(\left(\frac{f^{n}(0)}{n!}\right)x^n\right)
$$Let $\{a_n\}_{n\in \mathbb N }$ be $a_n=\frac{f^{n}(0)}{n!}$.
We have to assume that the Taylor series converges toward $f$ in an open interval $(-r,r)$ around zero. Then I have to show that if $a_{2n-1}=0$ for all $n\in \mathbb N$ so is $f(-x)=f(x)$ for all $x\in(-r,r)$.
How can I do it? I think I maybe can see on $kx^{2n}$ while all odd joints are zero while $a_{2n-1}=0$? But how can I prove it?

Comment: Isn't it enough to say that all terms are even functions ?

Answer (score 3):

We have $f(x)= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_{2n}x^{2n}$ for $x\in (-r,r).$

Firthermore: $(-x)^{2n}=x^{2n}.$

Can you proceed ?

Answer (score 1):

For all $x\in(-r,r)$ and all $m$,

$$\sum_{n=0}^m\frac{f^{(2n)}(0)}{(2n)!}(-x)^{2n}=\sum_{n=0}^m\frac{f^{(2n)}(0)}{(2n)!}x^{2n}$$

so that 
$$\lim_{m\to\infty}\sum_{n=0}^m\frac{f^{(2n)}(0)}{(2n)!}(-x)^{2n}=\lim_{m\to\infty}\sum_{n=0}^m\frac{f^{(2n)}(0)}{(2n)!}x^{2n}.$$

Answer (score 1):

If all coefficients $a_{2n-1}$ of Taylor expansion are zero, then the only remaining non-zero coefficients are the even ones, that is the coefficients of the form $a_{2n}x^{2n}$. Then notice that $x^2=(-x)^2$, therefore $a_{2n}x^{2n}=a_{2n}(-x)^{2n}$ and then
\begin{align*}
f(x)&=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_{2n}x^{2n}\nonumber\\
&=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_{2n}(-x)^{2n}\nonumber\\
&=f(-x)\nonumber
\end{align*}